# Typo3 Sorting on view page by overwrite Demand?

Tags: typo3, typoscript, typo3-8.x

```html
<f:link.page pageUid="{settings.listPid}"
                 additionalParams="{tx_news_pi1:{overwriteDemand:{order: 'crdate,ASC'}}}" addQueryString="1">
  Sort by crdate ASC
    </f:link.page>
 
 
 
<f:link.page pageUid="{settings.listPid}"
                 additionalParams="{tx_news_pi1:{overwriteDemand:{order: 'title,DESC'}}}" addQueryString="1">
  Sort by title DESC
    </f:link.page>
```

Sort by crdate ASC

Sort by title DESC

i added the two sort link on my page.i do one sort its working fine.when i click on second sort.its not sorting according to condition.

sounds like I need some condition that changes the ASC or DESC to the other value so when it is ASC the link changes to DESC?
to replace the hardcoded ASC/DESC text bits correct my code

Comment: <f:link.page pageUid="{settings.listPid}"
                 additionalParams="{tx_news_pi1:{overwriteDemand:{order: 'crdate,ASC'}}}" addQueryString="1">
  Sort by crdate ASC
    </f:link.page>
 
 
 
<f:link.page pageUid="{settings.listPid}"
                 additionalParams="{tx_news_pi1:{overwriteDemand:{order: 'title,DESC'}}}" addQueryString="1">
  Sort by title DESC
    </f:link.page>

Comment: anyone correct my code ?

Answer (score 0):

I think when you use addQueryString in your link (with an active order) you get the order double in your url?

Maybe you can try excluding the order from the link so you can be sure that there's only one order in the link:

`argumentsToBeExcludedFromQueryString="{0: {tx_news_pi1: {overwriteDemand: 'order'}}}"`

Not sure if the syntax is right but maybe this will guide you in the right direction.

Comment: its doesn't worked, same issue, i added on both the links inside additionalParams="{tx_news_pi1:{overwriteDemand:{order:'crdate,ASC'}}}" addQueryString="1" argumentsToBeExcludedFromQueryString="{0: {tx_news_pi1: {overwriteDemand: 'order'}}}">
                                                  .............   additionalParams="{tx_news_pi1:{overwriteDemand:{order:'views'}}}"  addQueryString="1" argumentsToBeExcludedFromQueryString="{0: {tx_news_pi1: {overwriteDemand: 'order'}}}">